# Actionscript - call symbol using variable as part of name (increment number) and change x/y position

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, symbols

Looked everywhere for this but can't find anything so I hope someone can help. Maybe there is something online but I am not putting it in the right words....

Using Actionscript I want to change the `x` and `y` multiple symbols I have that go up by row number and col number in their names i.e. `SP_01_01` - `SP_01-10`...... `SP_02_01`... etc

I need to access that symbol using two other variables holding the Number parts of the name and change the `x` and `y` values.

Here is what I have tried from what I've searched and thought was corrent

```
["SP__" + rownum + "_" + colnum].x = xcol;
["SP__" + rownum + "_" + colnum].y = yrow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call objects in this way:

```
getChildByName("SP__" + rownum + "_" + colnum).x = xcol;
getChildByName("SP__" + rownum + "_" + colnum).y = yrow;
```

This way even better:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
var cell:DisplayObject =  getChildByName("SP__" + rownum + "_" + colnum);
cell.x = xcol;
cell.y = yrow;
```

Comment: Thanks! I now have this - TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. - error though.    And the debug says that it is this line that I have just wrote.

Comment: @LewisSherlock are you sure that all these objects has instance names ? and all of them are like `SP__01_01` ?

Comment: Oh dear. Yes that is the reason. Now I've got another problem. I need to change the instance names of 200 symbols.

Comment: @LewisSherlock  why? tell me what is the names pattern and we'll change this line: `getChildByName("SP__" + rownum + "_" + colnum);`

Comment: each 01 contains _01 - _20 and there are 10 of the SP__01 if that makes sense. SP__01_01 - SP__01_20 .....SP__02_01 - SP__02_20. And btw they are definitely spelt the correct way with 2 underscores.           A better explaination might be that there are 10 rows and 20 columns. and each name represents one cell.

Comment: @LewisSherlock wait a minute , the problem is that rownum is in range 1,2,..,10 and not 01,02,..,10 and colnum is not 01,02,..,20 ?

Comment: I do now have a piece of code that creates a new string variable that holds the number value and adds a zero in front of it if it is below 10. This now works, but only if I change the instance name. But doing that for 200 symbols is going to take a bit of time.

Comment: @LewisSherlock so next time , do not create 200 symbols in Flash IDE , only with code! you know , something like `for(var i=0; i<200; i++) { var mySymbol = new MovieClip() }`